# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have been coding a library management system and whenever i try to add a book information with an image the error would occur:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Accessto the 
path C:\User\WINDOWS
10\source\repos\LibraryManagementSystem\LibraryManageme
ntSystem\BooksDirectory is denied.
at System.IO_Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String
fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean
checkingHost)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String
path, Boolean checkingHost)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
at LibraryManagementSystem.AddBooks.addBtn_Click(Object 
sender, EventArgs e) in
C:\User\Acer\source\repos\LibraryManagementSystem\Library
ManagementSystem\AddBooks.cs:line88
```

Here's the code:

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (picture.Image == null
                || booktitleTxt.Text == ""
                || authorTxt.Text == ""
                || published.Value == null
                || status.Text == ""
                || picture.Image == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill all blank fields", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                        connect.Open();
                        string insertData = "INSERT INTO books " +
                            "(book_title, author, published_date, status, image, date_insert) " +
                            "VALUES(@bookTitle, @author, @published_date, @status, @image, @dateInsert)";

                        string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\WINDOWS 10\source\repos\LibraryManagementSystem\LibraryManagementSystem\BooksDirectory\" +
                            booktitleTxt.Text + authorTxt.Text.Trim() + ".jpg");

                        string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

                        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                        {//Bellow is line 88
                         Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                        }

                        File.Copy(picture.ImageLocation, path, true);

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, connect))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookTitle", booktitleTxt.Text.Trim());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", authorTxt.Text.Trim());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@published_date", published.Value);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status.Text.Trim());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", path);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateInsert", today);

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            displayBooks();

                            MessageBox.Show("Added successfully!", "Information Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                            clearFields();
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connect.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried  giving full access to the forder BooksDirectory, even giving full access to the main folder itself it still wont work. I'm new in windows form so i still don't know much. All help is appreciated. Thank you guys.

Comment: To which user did you give the full access to directory. It must be given to the account/user the application runs on.

Comment: i have given full access as well as ownership to USER where visual studio runs but it still wont work

Comment: The path in the error message C:\User\WINDOWS
10\source\repos\LibraryManagementSystem\LibraryManageme
ntSystem\Books_Directory and the path in code are different, code has Booksdirectory while errormsg has Books_Directory.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Look at the path C:\User\WINDOWS
10\source Is this the intended destination. Probably you intended C:\User\WINDOWS
10\Users\User\source

Comment: You can first try running Visual Studio or the compiled application as administrator. If it still doesn't work, you can try to use `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` to create a folder in the path and check the error feedback of Visual Studio to further lock the issue.